# PayPal Smart Button server side implementation - Problems with capturing transaction - PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I've been trying to finish my server side implementation of the PayPal Smart Button and got stuck with capturing the transaction. I'm using a Sandbox account. I'm not sure if the problem is the order ID.

The response I get when trying to capture a transaction:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException: 
{"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
 "details[{"field":"order_id",
     "value":"$orderId",
     "location":"path",
     "issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
     "description":"Specified resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try again."}],
 "message":"The specified resource does not exist.",
 "debug_id":"df5cdbddfc1ea",
 "links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
 "rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]} in /usr/local/ampps/www/shop-files/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php:215
 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/ampps/www/shop-files/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php(100): PayPalHttp\HttpClient->parseResponse(Object(PayPalHttp\Curl)) 
#1 /usr/local/ampps/www/shop-files/capture-transaction.php(29): PayPalHttp\HttpClient->execute(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCaptureRequest))
 #2 /usr/local/ampps/www/shop-files/capture-transaction.php(62): Sample\CaptureIntentExamples\CaptureOrder::captureOrder('$orderId', in /usr/local/ampps/www/shop-files/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php on line 215
```

The response I get when creating a transaction:

```
{
    "id": "1XB529992P492602W",
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "reference_id": "default",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "GBP",
                "value": "12.00"
            },
            "payee": {
                "email_address": "sb-lxq8v1263761@business.example.com",
                "merchant_id": "SUHPR7WSYJPJQ"
            }
        }
    ],
    "create_time": "2020-10-14T08:36:00Z",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1XB529992P492602W",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=1XB529992P492602W",
            "rel": "approve",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1XB529992P492602W",
            "rel": "update",
            "method": "PATCH"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1XB529992P492602W/capture",
            "rel": "capture",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

My php code for creating a transaction:

```
<?php
namespace Sample\CaptureIntentExamples;
session_start();
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
require 'paypal-client.php';

class CreateOrder {
  public static function createOrder() {
    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body = self::buildRequestBody();
 
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute($request);
 
    echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    return $response;
  }
    private static function buildRequestBody() {
      return array(
        'intent'=>'CAPTURE',
        'application_context'=>
          array(
            'return_url'=>'https://localhost/basket.php',
            'cancel_url'=>'https://localhost/basket.php'
          ),
        'purchase_units'=>
          array(
            0=>
              array(
                'amount'=>
                  array(
                    'currency_code'=>'GBP',
                    'value'=>$_SESSION['total']
                  )             
              )
          )
      );
    }
}

if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  CreateOrder::createOrder(true);
}
?>
```

Code for capturing a transaction:

```
<?php

namespace Sample\CaptureIntentExamples;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCaptureRequest;
require 'paypal-client.php';

class CaptureOrder
{ 
  public static function captureOrder($orderId)
  {
    $request = new OrdersCaptureRequest($orderId);

    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute($request);
  
      echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    return $response;
  }
}
if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  CaptureOrder::captureOrder('$orderId', true);
}
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
createOrder: function(data) {
      return fetch('/shop-files/create-order.php', {
        method: 'post',
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      }).then(function(orderData) {
        return orderData.id;
      });
    },
    onShippingChange: function(data, actions) {
      if (data.shipping_address.country_code !== "GB") {
        return actions.reject();
      }
      return actions.resolve();
    },
    onApprove: function(data) {
      return fetch('/shop-files/capture-transaction.php', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
      }).then(function(res) {
          return res.json();
      }).then(function(orderData) {
          if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
              return actions.restart();
          }
          if (errorDetail) {
              var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
              if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
              if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
              return alert(msg);
          }
          alert('Transaction completed by ' + orderData.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link to an example "capture-transaction.php" or to share yours sans sensitive info if any is included? I've been following links in PayPal hell to get  current working examples of PHP scripts to capture what's returned from a PayPal Checkout button transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem line:

```
CaptureOrder::captureOrder('$orderId', true);
```

You are literally sending the text string inside the single quotes: '`$orderId`' to PayPal. The `$` and those 7 letters are going to PayPal.  You are *not* sending the *contents* of your $orderId variable.

Get rid of your string quotes:

```
CaptureOrder::captureOrder($orderId, true);
```

---

By the way, a detail about PHP (and incidentally, shell languages like bash) you may not be aware of:

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Basically, double quotes and single quotes behave differently in this respect.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the single quotes and it turned out that `$orderId` is undefined in `CaptureOrder::captureOrder($orderId, true);`  Inside of `captureOrder($orderId)` I tried `$orderId = $response->result->id` but it still says that the variable is undefined.

Comment: Seems your onApprove code also isn't doing anything to send the order's ID value in its fetch to your server. It has to, either as part of the fetch URL or as a data payload, and then your server needs to read it from wherever it's being sent to set $orderId before you use it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I added to my code for capturing a transaction to get the order's ID, right below `require 'paypal-client.php';`:

```
// Get JSON row data from the request
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Convert JSON string into array
$data = json_decode($json, true);
// Get the value of the key 'orderID'
$orderId = $data['orderID'];
```

I'm not sure if the comments explain exactly what is happening, so any correction would be most welcome.

Also the JavaScript code is a bit different with this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  orderID: data.orderID
})
```

added just below

```
headers: {
  'content-type': 'application/json'
},
```

It's working now. Many thanks Preston PHX for pointing me in the right direction again.